# What is equivalent of Spring scheduler in google guice?

Tags: spring, guice

I have a package that is implemented in Spring. I want to migrate it to Google Guice. The spring package uses Spring [scheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). What is the equivalent of Spring schedulre in Google Guice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Guice directly.

However, the [Guartz](http://99soft.github.io/guartz/userguide.html) project is an integration of the [Quartz](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz) project, in Guice, using a `@Scheduled` annotation as you would expect.